# How do I make a container that holds pointers of any type

Tags: c++, pointers

This may seem silly, but I'd like to make a container that holds pointers of any type, so that I can store every single pointer in there and then easily delete them later. I tried:

```
vector<void*> v;

v.push_back(new Dog());
v.push_back(new Cat());

cout <<  v[0]; // prints mem address
cout <<  v[1]; // prints another mem address
cout << *v[0]; // compiler yells at me
```

But apparently you can't dereference void pointers. Is there a way to make a generic container of pointers of any type, without having to make every single class extend a superclass called "Object" or something?

Comment: No, you can't dereference void pointers.

Comment: You can reinterpret_cast<> void pointers back to their real type and then dereference them. I have no idea how you would determine the real type of pointers though :)

Comment: If you want to delete them correctly, you need a smart pointer or some other form of type erasure.

Comment: `"so that I can store every single pointer in there and then easily delete them later."` You're doing it wrong. Store instances, not pointers to instances.

Comment: Also, you may want to share what you're trying to do (that is, "the bigger picture"), because I have no idea what are you expecting by trying to dereference a `void*` pointer, so I can't properly explain why you can't do this your way.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement pointer wrapper a template class which inherits from a common base class and place those to the container instead. Something along the lines:

```
class pointer_wrapper_base
{
public:
  virtual void delete_pointee()=0;
protected:
  void *m_ptr;
};

template<class T>
class pointer_wrapper: public pointer_wrapper_base
{
public:
  pointer_wrapper(T *ptr_) {m_ptr=ptr_;}
  virtual void delete_pointee()
  {
    delete (T*)m_ptr;
  }
};
```

Once you have this class, you can use poly-variant class for example, which is like variant class, but all the different variations have common base class. I have an implementation here if you want to have a look: http://sourceforge.net/p/spinxengine/code/HEAD/tree/sxp_src/core/utils.h (search for poly_pod_variant):

```
  std::vector<poly_pod_variant<pointer_wrapper_base> > x;
  x.push_back(pointer_wrapper<Cat>(new(Cat)));
  x[0]->delete_pointee();
```

Or if you are ok with dynamic allocation for the wrappers, then you can of course just store pointers to `pointer_wrap_base` to the vector, e.g.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<pointer_wrapper_base> > x;
x.push_back(std::unique_ptr<pointer_wrapper_base>(new(pointer_wrapper<Cat>)(new Cat)));
x[0]->delete_pointee();
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into using some of Boost's classes, such as boost::any, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html and their example code, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any/s02.html

Alternately, look at Boost's variant as well.

In general, learn Boost. It will blow you away and turbo charge your C++ development.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has a static type system. This means that types of all expressions must be known at compile time. The solution to your problem depends on what are you going to do with the objects.

Option 1: Have `Cat` and `Dog` derive from a class

This makes sense if all the objects have a common interface, and if you can make them to derive from a class.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> vec; // good practice - automatically manage 
                                          // dynamically allocated elements with
                                          // std::unique_ptr

vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Dog>()); // or vec.emplace_back(new Dog());
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Cat>()); // or vec.emplace_back(new Cat());

std::cout << *v[0];
```

Option 2: `boost::any`

This makes sense if the types are unrelated. For example, you storing `int`s and objects of your class. Obviously you can't make `int` derived from your class. So you use `boost::any` to store, and then cast it back to the type of the object. Exception of type `boost::bad_any_cast` is thrown if you cast to unrelated type.

```
std::vector<boost::any> vec;
vec.push_back(Dog());
vec.push_back(25);

std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(vec[1]);
```

Also, pointers. Solution to "I want manage my memory properly" is "Don't use `new` *and* `delete`" These are the tools to help you doing this, in no particular order:

- `std::string` instead of null-terminated strings
- `std::vector<T>` instead of `new T[]`
- `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead of raw pointers to polymorphic objects
- ...or `std::shared_ptr<T>` if you share them

Answer (score 0):

cout << * ((Dog *)v[0]);

I'm assuming here that your Dog class is stringifiable, otherwise you'll get a different kind of error, but your type conversion problem should be solved by (Dog *) type cast.